# How to filter multiple items from regerstry by using whrere-object -like?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am trying to get few items from registry by using `where-object`, I can only have one item filtered but multiple items...is there anything wrong with my script?

**This** code works fine for only one item

```
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ |  
ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath} |
Where-Object {
$_.Displayname -like 'adobe air'
} |
Select-Object DisplayName,DisplayVersion |
Sort-Object DisplayName |
Out-GridView
```

**But** if i set it to filter multiple items, it runs, ends, without any result... any idea why?

```
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ |  
ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath} |
Where-Object {
$_.Displayname -like 'adobe air' -and
$_.Displayname -like 'Java*' -and
$_.Displayname -like 'TeamViewer*'
} |
Select-Object DisplayName,DisplayVersion |
Sort-Object DisplayName |
Out-GridView
```

If I use

```
Where-Object {
$_.Displayname -like "Security*"
}
```

It only gives me 3 items matches `Security`, not all of them, Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the logic you put in.  `-and` means both need to be true, use `-or` instead.

Comment: well...lol, looks like i asked a noob question lol. Thanks, it works.

Comment: Your example will only get items that start with "Security"  if you put the "*" on both sides you'll get everything with Security in the name.

Comment: It trips me up a lot, that's why I know the difference.

Comment: For the "Security" one, it only gives me 3 items even i use * on both side, also `update*`, if i try with `*update*`, all i got were errors, i guess must be something wrong with $_.displayname, should use other properties.